# Infinitive usage in grammar

Tags: grammaticality

is it okay if i say that
 "is it the place only gents to stand".
I am in confusion.
please reply as soon as possible so as to
 i can clear my doubt.i will be waiting for your answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it should be:

> **Is it the place only for gents to  stand?**

Comment: What  is the  correct  answer  for this  question?

Comment: What is the  correct  answer for  this?

Comment: You answer is correct

Comment: @DeepSen.If  you think that  it is correct, you can accept the  answer by pressing  below the  triangle